# Gas pipe trap nipple relative to flow direction

Tags: plumbing, pipe, natural-gas

I know that a natural gas black pipe requires a 3-4" trap nipple below the turn when the flow in the pipe changes direction from vertical to horizontal, in order to catch possible particles coming from the supply.

Is such a trap required in the opposite case, when the pipe turns from horizontal to vertical? Can I just use an elbow going up or do I still need a tee with a short nipple that the flow would not be going into but particles may still get trapped in thanks to gravity?

Comment: I thought they were only recommended after the shut off prior to a regulator , a dead leg hanging down, I think I have also heard it called a trap.

Comment: It is easy enough to put in a "T" /nipple/cap instead of an elbow. You also have a possible future access.